# RecyclerView не корректно работает с GridLayoutManager(this, 2)

Tags: android, recyclerview, kotlin

У меня есть два положения отображения списка, в вертикальном положении в одну колонку (работает по умолчанию), а вот в горизонтальном я указываю через код.

```
class RecyclerViewActivity: AppCompatActivity(){
    ...
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.recyclerview_activity)
        ...
        if (resources.configuration.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){
            val staggeredGridVertical = GridLayoutManager(this, 2)
            rv?.setLayoutManager(staggeredGridVertical)

        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Теперь в этом положении я не могу контролировать RecyclerView.

Этот кусок кода отвечает за подгруздку контента, а в горизонтальном положении он отказывается работать, из-за этого во время скролла возникает бесконечная подзагрузка контента, т.к условие срабатывает.

```
rv?.addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView?, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)

        totalItemCount = llm.itemCount //get
        lastVisibleItem = llm.findLastVisibleItemPosition()
        System.out.println("totalItemCount -.> ${totalItemCount}")
        System.out.println("lastVisibleItem -.> ${lastVisibleItem}")

        if (totalItemCount == lastVisibleItem+1) {
            val handler = Handler()
            handler.postDelayed(Runnable {
                mAdapter!!.notifyItemInserted(persons!!.size - 1)

                persons!!.add(CardRV("....", "....", "https://prev.jpg", "123", "01.02.18"))

                mAdapter!!.notifyItemRemoved(persons!!.size)
            }, 2000)
        }
    }
})
```

Все это явно из-за GridLayoutManager, но я не знаю как это исправить.

**Adapter**

```
class Adapter internal constructor( var persons: List<CardRV>, context : Context)
    : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

    var mContext = context
    private val ITEM_VIEW_TYPE_BASIC = 0
    private val ITEM_VIEW_TYPE_FOOTER = 1

    class ProgressViewHolder internal constructor(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        var progressBar: ProgressBar = itemView.findViewById<View>(R.id.progress_bar) as ProgressBar
    }

    class ViewHolders internal constructor(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        internal var cv: CardView
        internal var personName: TextView
        internal var personAge: TextView
        internal var personPhoto: ImageView
        internal var like: ImageView
        internal var likeCaunt : TextView
        internal var date : TextView

        init {
            cv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv) as CardView
            personName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.person_name) as TextView
            personAge = itemView.findViewById(R.id.person_age) as TextView
            personPhoto = itemView.findViewById(R.id.person_photo) as ImageView
            //Анимация нажатия ImageView
            like = itemView.findViewById(R.id.like) as ImageView
            like.setOnClickListener({v->
                like.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(itemView.context, R.anim.alpha))
            })
            likeCaunt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.likeCaunt)
            date = itemView.findViewById(R.id.date)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(viewGroup: ViewGroup, i: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder? {
        System.out.println("onCreateViewHolder -> $i")
        //create the view for each corresponding viewtype
        return when(i) {
            0 -> {
                val v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.context).inflate(
                    R.layout.item, viewGroup, false)
                ViewHolders(v)
            }
            else -> {
                val v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.context).inflate(
                    R.layout.prograss_bar, viewGroup, false)
                ProgressViewHolder(v)
            }
        }
    }

    //Здесь работает setOnClickListener
    override fun onBindViewHolder(personViewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder?, i: Int) {

        if (personViewHolder is ViewHolders) {
            personViewHolder.personName.text = persons[i].name

            personViewHolder.personName.setOnClickListener { v ->
                val intent = Intent(v.context, Browser::class.java)
                intent.putExtra("fname", "FDFSF")
                startActivity(mContext, intent, null)
            }
            personViewHolder.personAge.text = persons[i].age
            personViewHolder.likeCaunt.text = persons[i].likeCaunt
            personViewHolder.date.text = persons[i].date

            Glide.with(mContext)
                .load(persons[i].photoUrl)
                .into((personViewHolder as ViewHolders).personPhoto)
        } else {
            //Отображаем прогресс бар когда сиписок достиг предела
            if (!false) {
                (personViewHolder as ProgressViewHolder).progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                personViewHolder.progressBar.isIndeterminate = true
            } else
                (personViewHolder as ProgressViewHolder).progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int { return persons.size }
    //Возвращает 0 или 1
    //Подходит для отрисовки item
    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        System.out.println("${position}")
        return if (position+1 != persons.size){ITEM_VIEW_TYPE_BASIC} else {ITEM_VIEW_TYPE_FOOTER}
    }

    //Сохраняем состояние.
    class Save(context: Context?) : RecyclerView(context) {
        var spanCount = 1
        private val manager: GridLayoutManager? = null
        override fun onMeasure(widthSpec: Int, heightSpec: Int) {
            super.onMeasure(widthSpec, heightSpec)
            if (columnWidth > 0) {
                spanCount = Math.max(1, getMeasuredWidth() / columnWidth);
                manager?.setSpanCount(spanCount);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**XML**

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:title="RV"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/SpinnerCustom"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:pointerIcon="top_right_diagonal_double_arrow"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:entries="@array/catlist"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"/>

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        style="?android:progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/appBarLayout" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/appBarLayout" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Вот небольшой пример**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

В общем сам подход реализации кастомного RV был плохой. Нашел другой https://github.com/googlesamples/android-RecyclerView

Который полностью подходит для моих целей.